Acumatica Test SDK processing grid incorrectly returns no rows
I'm using Acumatica 23.211.0017 with Test SDK to automate SO.50.30.00 Process Shipment. It's my first attempt to use Test SDK, so apologies in advance if the answer seems obvious!
I have an extension class that inherits from the wrapper SO503000_SOInvoiceShipment and exposes the Orders grid. I can interact with my custom fields on the Filter and the standard Action drop-down (from my scripts).
But although I can see in Chrome that the Orders grid has refreshed and shows the correct rows; I can't access those rows from within my test scripts.
While
InvoiceShipment.Orders.AllPagesRowsCount() returns 3 (which is correct)
InvoiceShipment.Orders.RowsCount() returns 0 (expected 3)
And
InvoiceShipment.Orders.SelectRow(1);
InvoiceShipment.Orders.Row.ShipmentNbr.Value returns null (expected a shipment number for a SOShipment record)
I've tried re-selecting the Action, and using the PageFirst method on the grid. No difference.
    public class SO503000_InvoiceShipment : GeneratedWrappers.Acumatica.SO503000_SOInvoiceShipment
    {
        public c_filter_form Filters => base.Filter_form;
        public c_orders_grid Orders => base.Orders_grid;
    }

    public class ReadShipments : Check
    {
        public override void Execute()
        {
            using (TestExecution.CreateTestStepGroup("Step 1 - shipments for Prepare Invoice"))
            {
                PxLogin.LoginToDestinationSite();

                var InvoiceShipment = new SO503000_InvoiceShipment();
                InvoiceShipment.OpenScreen();

                InvoiceShipment.Filters.Action.Select("Prepare Invoice");

                InvoiceShipment.Orders.RowsCount().VerifyIsGreaterThan(0); //, "Need some orders to be listed in the grid for a valid test");

                for (int i = 1; i <= InvoiceShipment.Orders.AllPagesRowsCount(); i++)
                {
                    InvoiceShipment.Orders.SelectRow(i);
                    InvoiceShipment.Orders.Row.ShipmentNbr.Value.VerifyNotEquals("", "Expected a Shipment number");
                }
            }
        }
    }


why not just use AllPagesRowsCount()? For Shipment nbr try InvoiceShipment.Orders.Columns.ShipmentNbr

It looks like InvoiceShipment.Orders.Columns.ShipmentNbr will give me the value of the filter set on that column, (It has type Controls.Editors.Selector.SelectorColumnFilter).

The other odd thing is that InvoiceShipment.Orders.SelectRow(1) succeeds. Row 1 becomes highlighted within the grid displayed in Chrome.  Which tells me that InvoiceShipment.Orders is mapped to the correct element on the screen. InvoiceShipment.Orders.Row seems to give the correct element too; but null is given for every Value on every control on that Row.

I suggest you not use the Verify commands, the SDK doc makes me think that the GreaterThan versions only work with certain controls. Try something like this
for (int i = 1; i <= InvoiceShipment.Orders.AllPagesRowsCount(); i++)
{
    InvoiceShipment.Orders.SelectRow(i);
    var ShipmentNbr = InvoiceShipment.Orders.Row.ShipmentNbr.GetValue();
    if (ShipmentNbr != ...)
}

